# Issue while setting slider thumb at a particular point if slider maximum value is too high?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uislider

I am working in xamarin forms. I have slider whose maximum value is more than 200. I want to move the slider thumb at particular point on slider for example at 120, but it becomes very tough to put the thumb at particular point. This happens with large maximum values. If values are less then its working fine.

So is there any solution so that we can move the slider's thumb easily at any point if slider's maximum value is very large?

Comment: You can change the amount a slider value increases by per movement up the slider, have you looked at that?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Through which property I can change the amount a slider value increases? Also it is working fine if value is low like 20 or 30 or etc. But we face the issue only if slider's maximum value is too large.

Comment: Its 'StepValue' the answer below is a good example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the increase value like this GIF.
[image]

Here is code.I set the StepValue to 20

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private double StepValue;
    private Slider SliderMain;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StepValue = 20.0;
        BindingContext = new HslColorViewModel();
        SliderMain = new Slider
        {
            Minimum = 0.0f,
            Maximum = 200.0f,
            Value = 0.0f,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand

        };
        SliderMain.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        SliderMain.ValueChanged += OnSliderValueChanged;

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { SliderMain },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

        };

    }
    void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newStep = Math.Round(e.NewValue / StepValue);

        SliderMain.Value = newStep * StepValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: @anand Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.